# Save different byte formats to file as readable text in Python

Tags: python, casting, escaping, hex

I am attempting to save a list of strings and hex values (the latter of which is in different representations) as a human readable string into a file in Python.

```
['TX', '\x12', '0x2', '0x15', '0xe6', '0x86', '0xce', '\x13']
```

Which gets saved to the file like this

```
TX0x20x150xe60x860xce
```

as you can see, all the hex representations which utilize the escape sequence get stored, not as a readable version of their values, but as  special characters.  My goal is to be able to identify these values as they come through (which I attempted using     if "//" in newString to no avail), and then to convert them to the hex representation "0x##" so they can be stored and read by a person later on.

Comment: How do you tell the difference between 0x2 and 0x30 0x78 0x32?

Comment: Those all appear to be in the same hex representation format.  The main issue I am having is that characters which are represented using the escape character "\x" end up getting converted to their representative ASCII characters which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: They aren't being *converted* to ASCII, they already *are* ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my question ended up being that in order to save the values as a representation of the hex values that I was looking for I ended up needing to use the following code:

```
    def log(self, mode, data):
    for i,d in enumerate(data):
        if not isinstance(d,str):
            data[i] = hex(d)
        elif self.is_hex(d):
            data[i] = binascii.hexlify(d)
```

This alllowed the data I wanted to be stored in a format that could be read.  Thank you to [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) for your help, as well as the following [Dev Dungeon : Working with Binary Data](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/working-binary-data-python) for all its excellent info.